# Is Slack's Multi Login Design Good for UX?

Tags: login

From a user experience standpoint, does it hurt that a user that is part of multiple teams on Slack, is required to log in to each of them individually, and to type in each team's url/name individually? As opposed to going to one site, logging in once, and accessing any/all of their teams.

I understand the benefits in their architecture from a technical standpoint; however, for me as a user this seems counter intuitive.

Are there any studies or evidence in general that are in favor of, or against this type of user flow?

Answer (score 1):

It might not be UX friendly but it certainly is security friendly.

By asking credentials to login into each team, Slack adds an extra security check to ensure that the right person is using the right account.

Is it a pain in the ass? Yes.

Could they have offered the ability to have more lax security (i.e keep me logged in or something equivalent) for specific teams? Also yes.

Could it have also been abused with the wrong person entering a Company's private chat and reading messages/plans/etc.? Definitely yes.

So, considering that Slack was first marketed as a corporate/startup tool for a work environment I think we further understand why they made that choice. It is also safe to say that the majority of their income comes from these corporate clients who do enjoy the knowledge that there is an extra security measure in place.

Comment: Yes. This is fairly common. Higher security generally means worse user experience. And often (in my experience) security measures aren't put through the same UX scrutiny as everything else.